# What are the elements forming the subgroup $H = \langle a,b \rangle$ of $\Bbb C^\ast$ when $a = e^{2\pi i/5}$ and $b=e^{2\pi i/7}$? Is $H$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> What are the elements forming the subgroup $H = \langle a,b \rangle$ of $\Bbb C^\ast$ when $a = e^{2\pi i/5}$ and $b=e^{2\pi i/7}$? Is $H$ cyclic?

For the subgroup $H$ we have that $H=\{ae^{2\pi i/5} + be^{2\pi i/7} \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ but I don't know if it's supposed to get some better description for it?

$H$ is cyclic if I can generate it with single element, but I don't think it's possible to do this?

Comment: Since $\Bbb C^*$ is a group under multiplications, why do you consider numbers of the form $ae^{2\pi i/5}\color{red}+be^{2\pi i/7}$?

Comment: Every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic. Plenty of threads disuss that. So if you cannot find a generator, can you show that $H$ is finite?

Comment: Another well covered formela is for the order of $ab$ in an abelian group, when the orders of $a$ and $b$ are known. You could also use that :-)

Comment: Also $|a|=5 $ and $|b|=7$

Comment: @SouravGhosh A number of authors, indeed, use $|a|$ to denote the order of an element of a group, but this is not universal. Don't know about this asker :-) Anyway, because we are dealing with complex numbers the notation may be a bit confusing. After all, the complex numbers also have an absolute value!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it's a convenient notation. But in that case it is not because of the presence of absolute value. Good suggestion.

Comment: To solve it, guess that the generator is $e^{2\pi i/35}$.  Then see if you can find $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ where $(e^{2\pi i/5})^m (e^{2\pi i/7})^n=e^{2\pi i/35}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

1. $H=\langle a, b\rangle=\{a^mb^n \mid m, n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$
2. The order $O(a)$ of $a$ is $5$ and the order $O(b)$ of $b$ is $7$.
3. $\Bbb{C}^{\star}$ is an abelian group and $\gcd(O(a), O(b))=1$, hence $O(ab) =35$
4. Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.
5. $|G|<\infty$.Then $G=\langle g\rangle$ iff $|G|=O(g)$

> $H=\langle e^{\frac{2\pi i}{35}}\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_{35}$